# Agregar el código fuente a un jar en Java pero aparece esto <Source Attachment (none): non modifiable> usando Gradle y migracion de java 8 a java 11

Tags: java, gradle, migracion

estoy en un proyecto de migración de Java 8 a Java 11 y un jar me está causando problemas, específicamente el jar Jide-grids, debido a esto se realizó la compra del código fuente de esta herramienta y quiero incluirlo en el Jar para así poder debbugear el código y encontrar con el error, pero eclipse en Builth path> configure build path>Java build path> Libraries si intento usar la opción Source attachment aparece como non-modifiable, y no me permite incluir el código fuente en el jar, estoy usando Gradle, alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: Y por qué no usas el código fuente al que ahora tienes acceso y lo enlazas directamente a tu proyecto, permitiéndote generar una versión "completa" del mismo, en vez de intentar meter el fuente en la versión de la librería?

Comment: Terminé haciendo eso